# Generate a filename based on a URL on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, nsstring, plist

I need to store some persistent data in my application that should be specific to the URL i am requesting data from.
For example, if i make a request to http://www.example.com/a, i need to store a plist in my documents folders that is unique to that URL. So if another request is made to the same URL, i can go edit that same plist in my documents folder.

Temporarily I am generating it this way but i need a better solution:

```
NSString *filename = stringForURL;
filename = [filename stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"__"];
filename = [filename stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"?" withString:@""];
filename = [filename stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"plist"];
```

And then i write my dictionary with that filename.

Edit: Ok I don't think i explained myself clearly. I basically want to generate a unique filename for a given URL. Any same URL should generate the same filename, and 2 different URLs should generate a different filename.

Comment: What's your question? It seems you are just looking for a code review here. Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com if that is all you want.

Comment: Sure, try CR - but ideally provide more context than just a specific little snippet. Great CR questions tend to involve at least a method, or a class.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage implementation. That might help you.

Comment: Ok I don't think i explained myself clearly. I basically want to generate a unique filename for a given URL. Any same URL should generate the same filename, and 2 different URLs should generate a different filename.

Comment: Thanks Shineeth Hamza, that was quite helpful. I will just use a MD5 hash to generate the filename.

Answer (score 2):

Using an MD5 hash where the key is the URL did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your problem you want to get the same URL back after you have changed it. If so use the same code on when looking for the string.

Create an array of all the urls you have changed and saved.

```
NSString *theURLyouAreLookingFor= "myURL" ;
theURLyouAreLookingFor = [filename stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"__"];
theURLyouAreLookingFor = [filename stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"?" withString:@""];
```

And the use `isEqualTo:` with the `theURLyouAreLookingFor` and look it up in the array of saved URLs.

Not the best way of explaining this, but hope it helps.